# using patindex to replace characters

Tags: t-sql, patindex

I have a table with a name column in it that contains names like:

**A & A Turf

C & D Railways

D & B Railways**

I have the following query that will get me the correct columns I want
`select name from table where patindex('_ & _ %', name) > 0`

What I need to accomplish is making anything with that type of pattern collapsed. Like this
**A&A Turf

C&D Railways

D&B Railways**

I'm also looking how I can do the same thing with single letter followed by a space followed by another single letter followed by a space then words with more then one letter like this
**A F Consulting -> AF Consulting

D B Catering -> DB Consulting**

but only if the single letter stuff is at the beginning of the value.
Example would be if the name has the pattern mentioned above anywhere in the name then don't do anything unless it's at the beginning

**ALBERS, J K -> ALBERS, J K** 
  This would not change because it's a name  and it's not at the beginning.

So something like this would be the desired result:

```
 Original Name      New Name            Rule
____________       __________           ___________
A & K Consulting    A&K Consulting     Space Taken out between & for single characters
C B Finance         CB Finance         space taken out only if beginning beginning
Albert J K          Albert J K         not at beginning so left alone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without PATINDEX.  Because what needs to be replaced is at the start, and has fixed patterns.  So you already know the positions.

Example snippet:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO @Table (name) VALUES
('A & K Consulting'),
('C B Finance'),
('Albert J K'),
('Foo B & A & R');

SELECT 
name AS OldName,
(CASE 
 WHEN name LIKE '[A-Z] [A-Z] %' THEN STUFF(name,2,1,'') 
 WHEN name LIKE '[A-Z] & [A-Z] %' THEN STUFF(name,2,3,'&')
 ELSE name
 END) AS NewName
FROM @Table;
```

Test on rextester [here](http://rextester.com/WVTW64840)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is straightforward: replace " & " with "&".  The second I'll have to take more time.

Comment: Might have that later in the name like Charlie & Company so I don't want to do that